# Route53 subdomain not resolved with nslookup

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront, nslookup

## My problem

I am trying to build a personal CDN to share static file with my contacts. The design includes an S3 bucket, a CloudFront distribution and a subdomain registered via Route53, all configured using Terraform.

However, I can reach my files via S3 and Cloudfront, but not via my subdomain (`cdn.adamatan.com`).

## What's working

### S3

```
curl http://cdn.adamatan.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html
```

### CloudFront

```
curl https://d36tl9ayobqfgg.cloudfront.net/index.html
```

## What's broken

I can't get the files using the subdomain. Moreover, the `nslookup` for `cdn.adamatan.com` and `adamatan.con` do not work. I think that I've misconfigured Route53 somehow.

## Configuration

### Domain

[image]

### Hosted Zone

[image]

### Terraform configuration

```
variable "hosted_zone" {
  default = "adamatan.com"
}

variable "domain" {
  default = "cdn.adamatan.com"
}

variable "aws_region" {
  default = "us-east-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  region  = "${var.aws_region}"
  profile = "personal"
  version = "~> 1.1"
}

/*
   The S3 bucket storing the files. It must bear the same name as the domain
   pointing to it. See https://gist.github.com/danihodovic/a51eb0d9d4b29649c2d094f4251827dd,
   and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5048129/2966951
*/
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "adamatan_cdn_bucket" {
  bucket = "${var.domain}"
  acl = "public-read"

  policy = <<EOF
{
      "Version":"2008-10-17",
      "Statement":[{
        "Sid":"AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Principal": {"AWS": "*"},
        "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
        "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::${var.domain}/*"]
      }]
    }
  EOF

  tags {
    Description = "Origin bucket for my personal CDN"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_zone" "cdn_zone" {
  name = "${var.hosted_zone}"
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "root_domain" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.cdn_zone.zone_id}"
  name = "${var.domain}"
  type = "A"

  alias {
    name = "${aws_cloudfront_distribution.adamatan_cdn_distribution.domain_name}"
    zone_id = "${aws_cloudfront_distribution.adamatan_cdn_distribution.hosted_zone_id}"
    evaluate_target_health = false
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "adamatan_cdn_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = "${var.domain}.s3.amazonaws.com"
    origin_id   = "${var.domain}"
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true
  comment             = "Permanent public file distribution"
  default_root_object = "index.html"

  aliases = ["${var.domain}"]

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "${var.domain}"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "allow-all"
    min_ttl                = 60
    default_ttl            = 300
    max_ttl                = 86400
  }

  price_class = "PriceClass_All"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = true
  }
}


output "domain" {
  value = "${var.domain}"
}

output "cdn_domain" {
  value = "${aws_cloudfront_distribution.adamatan_cdn_distribution.domain_name}"
}
```

## My question

**How can I map my subdomain (`cdn.adamatan.com`) to my cloudfront distribution (`d36tl9ayobqfgg.cloudfront.net`) using Terraform (preferably with SSL support)?**

Comment: Similar question / scenario was asked a while back, [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/845860/distributed-large-file-hosting/845865?noredirect=1#comment1084590_845865). Not sure if it's relevant but might be worth a read.

Comment: @Tim Thanks! Read the question, seems to address a different issue. My problems is actually Route53 specific (DNS does not work correctly).

Comment: Is the domain setup as a public or private? I see it in terraform... but just want to verify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Amazon Hosted Zone you have different set of name servers than at your registrar.

```
Domain Name: ADAMATAN.COM
Registrar: Gandi SAS
Name Server: NS-1193.AWSDNS-21.ORG
Name Server: NS-1889.AWSDNS-44.CO.UK
Name Server: NS-4.AWSDNS-00.COM
Name Server: NS-1193.AWSDNS-21.ORG
```

None of the name servers above answers to `adamatan.com SOA` & `cdn.adamatan.com`. These name servers don't have your domain configured at them, while the set of servers on your zone have:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.245
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.59
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.22
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.89
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.45
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.248
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.169
cdn.adamatan.com.       60      IN      A       13.33.23.94

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
adamatan.com.           172800  IN      NS      ns-1511.awsdns-60.org.
adamatan.com.           172800  IN      NS      ns-1730.awsdns-24.co.uk.
adamatan.com.           172800  IN      NS      ns-378.awsdns-47.com.
adamatan.com.           172800  IN      NS      ns-936.awsdns-53.net.
```

Go to the domain management on your Gandi account and change your name servers accordingly. The NS records at the parent (`.com`) zone should match the ones in your own (`adamatan.com`).

Keep in mind that the `TTL` on both zones is `172800` seconds i.e. 48 hours. It may take up to two days for these changes to take effect. `dig adamatan.com NS @a.gtld-servers.net.` shows if they have been updated on the root name servers of `.com`, and that's when the count actually begins.

Comment: Thanks! Taking a look at it. The domain is registered at Amazon as well. I'll change the records ([must be manual for now](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/88), Terraform does not support domain dns servers changes).

Comment: FWIW, when a domain is registered with AWS, the underlying registrar is often Gandi SAS because Route 53 is not, itself, a registrar but a [reseller](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-concepts.html#route-53-concepts-domain-reseller) of Gandi and another entity called Amazon Registrar... so changes are made through the AWS interface, but the WHOIS doesn't necessarily say Amazon.  The discrepancy between nameservers is usually caused by [deleting a hosted zone and putting it back](https://serverfault.com/a/838396/153161), which doesn't do what some people assume.